# jQuery Mobile listview or button refresh doesn't update theme

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

Could you try this simple example and tell me what's going wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/unQWP/1/. The `li` theme is changed, but the listview refresh cannot update it.

The same problem occurs if I want to update the right button theme: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/unQWP/2/. I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined
```

=================================================

Can I know why this ALMOST work but doesnt.., (need 2 click, to change, and can't get back)

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/unQWP/5/

it should toggle theme

Comment: great it seems in my example it's "b" theme that can't work, works with "e"

Comment: Switching between any two themes should work using the code I've posted in my answer. I just used theme `e` because it is move clearly visually distinct from theme `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by using the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kE8GJ/. Note that the most important part of the code is this conditional:

```
var element;

if ($(this).hasClass("ui-li-link-alt")) {
    element = $(this);
}
else {
    element = $(this).closest('li.ui-li');
}

element
    .removeClass("ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-hover-c")
    .addClass("ui-btn-hover-e")
    .attr("data-theme", "e");
```

This will correctly set the theme on either the `li` element for the left-side buttons or the `a` element for the right-side buttons, which ultimately has the effect of applying the new theme to the clicked element, which seems to be your goal.

As for the `TypeError` that you were seeing, I think it is related to your `.button()` calls. The elements in jQuery Mobile listviews aren't typically dealt with as buttons, so such calls may cause problems. All calls like `.trigger('create')` should be made at the `listview` level.

---

In response to your edit, you must manually add and remove the classes to successfully toggle the theme. Otherwise, the classes for the old theme will still be present. For example, if you switch from theme `e` to `c`, the `ui-btn-up-e` or `ui-btn-hover-e` will still be on the `li` element, so it will appear to not toggle back to theme `c`. You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/wu86C/.

The most important code is the second line here (and the equivalent for toggling from `c` to `e`):

```
var li = $(this).closest('li');
li.removeClass("ui-btn-up-e ui-btn-hover-e").addClass("ui-btn-hover-c");
```

Comment: @JC thx again, 1 detail: the borders on the right button are colored in yellow also, would be better without, any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/kE8GJ/2/

Comment: @cyril: That may be difficult to change, as the border is on the `li` element, which is what is getting styled. And that's really moving out of the scope of the initial question. You might have more luck posting that as a new question, which could also help to get more eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but with jquery mobile you not have your html structure, but your "a tag inside li" is wrapped inside some div.

In effect if you simple try:

```
$('#mylist a').click(function() {
        console.log($(this));        
        $('#li1').attr("data-theme", "e");
        alert( $('#li1').attr("data-theme"));
        $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
    });
```

In your first fiddle, this change the theme.